# Output not displaying after echo

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to format my output based on the result of a certain command. However, it's not printing out. Can you guys let me know what I am missing out.

```
VID=$(grep -iE $vvwwn ${TPAR_TEMP}/vvid_${TPAR_NAME} > ${TPAR_TEMP}/tvvid 2> /dev/null)

    TVVID=$(cat ${TPAR_TEMP}/tvvid |awk '{print$3}' 2> /dev/null)

            if [ "${TVVID}" = "32" ]; then
                            sh templ1
                            echo "$VID"
                   else
                            sh templ2 
                            echo "$VID"     
            fi
```

`templ1` is

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "========================================================================================================"
awk '
BEGIN {printf "%-27s %-6s %-32s %-8s %-8s %-9s %-4s\n" , "Name", "State", "VV_WWN", "VSize_MB", "Usr_Used_MB", "UsrCPG", "Prov"}'
echo "========================================================================================================"
```

Comment: `VID` is empty because you sent the output of the `grep` into a file instead of letting the command substitution be assigned to the variable - as Orion said in another comment. You may be able to use `tee` if you need both.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, `VID` is not empty. I'm sure of it as I tested and echoed it after. But it's all good. was able to figure it out. thanks

Comment: Well, what was the solution? Using the code you showed it's not possible for `VID` to have any contents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$VID` been empty due to the redirect in the command `grep -iE $vvwwn ${TPAR_TEMP}/vvid_${TPAR_NAME} > ${TPAR_TEMP}/tvvid`, To make the problem easier fill in the variables and run the command in your terminal.

Comment: i tried removing the 2> redirection and still no output. I did manually run and fill up the variable and it did work but the actual script is still not working. :(

Comment: the problem is with the redirect to the file `${TPAR_TEMP}/vvid_${TPAR_NAME} > ${TPAR_TEMP}/tvvid`

Comment: I don't think the problem is on that part. It is part of a for loop which i also redirected to a file. Which is also working.